# UWP C# .net StreamSocket with User Token in HostName

Tags: c#, uwp, access-token, hostname, stream-socket-client

Is there a way to format the HostName for a StreamSocket to include a user token? I get a "Parameter is Incorrect" exceptions when I try to use a URI with the a user Token. I have had success with a MessageWebSocket but I need a StreamSocket because it is able to (easily) run in the background on Windows 10 UWP. Here is my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static async void ConnectToStreamSocket()
    {
        StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket();
        string hostUri = "//example.myexample.com/websocket/dfkjlkdfskldklfdkddkfdkffjf";
        HostName host = new HostName(hostUri);           
        string proto = "wss";
        await socket.ConnectAsync(host, proto);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get a "Parameter is Incorrect" exceptions when I try to use a URI with the a user Token.

The parameter of  [HostName constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br207118.aspx) is not a [URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.uri.aspx), but a string that contains a `hostname` or an IP address. According to the description of the `hostName` parameter, it can contain one of the following:

> - The name of a host that can be resolved by the Domain Name System (DNS) or by another namespace provider.
> - The name of a host that matches a string in the following file on the local computer: %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> - A string that contains an IPv4 or an IPv6 network address of the host.

For `"//example.myexample.com/websocket/dfkjlkdfskldklfdkddkfdkffjf"`, this is a URI that don't meet above requirements so that the it cannot be recognized by [`HostName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.hostname.aspx) class. Value like `example.myexample.com` can be recognized.

For why you can successfully use [`MessageWebSocket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.messagewebsocket.aspx) class, this is because [`MessageWebSocket.ConnectAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.messagewebsocket.connectasync.aspx) method requires a URI parameter as you provided.

> but I need a StreamSocket because it is able to (easily) run in the background on Windows 10 UWP.

**`WebSockets`** provide a mechanism for fast, secure two-way communication between a client and a server over the web using HTTP(S). **`Socket`** can be used for communicating with other device. They are not the same things, we cannot simply transfer `WebSockets` to `StreamSocket`. More details about `WebSockets` and `StreamSockets` in uwp please reference the official documents [`Sockets`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets) and [`WebSockets`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/websockets).

But `WebSockets` can be used in background, you may not need `StreamSocket`. If you are using WebSockets in background, you must use [ControlChannelTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701032). Details for how to use WebSockets with ControlChannelTrigger please reference [ControlChannelTrigger with WebSockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/network-communications-in-the-background#controlchanneltrigger-with-websockets).

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm now using the ControlChannelTrigger  and it is successfully triggering the my background task when data comes over the MessageWebSocket. I have since been searching for how to get the data received over the socket into the background task so that I can process it. I have not found anything online explaining the process so far.

Comment: @JamesB, please try to reference [this sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ControlChannelTrigger-91f6bed8). By the way, if my answer helped  you, please mark as accepted. If you still have new issues you can open new thread.